# Xpath operation on xml file

Tags: xml, xpath, pyspark

I am trying to load a xml file as string and then I want to do some xpath operation on it

Below Work

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
<note>\
  <to>Tove</to>\
  <from>Jani</from>\
  <heading>Reminder</heading>\
  <body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body>\
</note>']],['value'])

df.printSchema()
df=df.selectExpr("xpath(value,'note/to/text()')")
```

Now I am trying to put the XML in a file and load it as text and then do similar operation on it

```
xml_file="\\path to the file,contents are exactly same as above example"
df=spark.read.option("wholetext", True).text(xml_file)
df=df.selectExpr('xpath(value,"note/to/text()")')
df.show()

Error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 28.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 28.0 (TID 33) (10.191.197.4 executor 0): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading expression &#39;note/to/text()&#39

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Premature end of file
```

Please can somebody help,exact same operation fails when trying to read from file.
**I DO NOT want to read the file as xml,due to project requirements I have to load the entire XML as string and then do xpath operations to extract specific tags**

Please suggest

Comment: I am able to do same operation with same text present as text file are you making sure all of that xml is in single line else data will be broken in rows and as error says it doesnt know in which row tag starts and where it ends

Comment: yes you are correct ..converting to single line worked

Comment: If putting in same line solved it then can I put it as an answer which you can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable reason you are getting a premature end is that the XML is in multiple lines so when read it breaks into multiple rows and spark cannot identify where a tag starts and where it ends so try having the text in a file in a single line before using Xpath